# The difference between Arrays and Sets in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, set

Can someone tell the difference between ***Set*** and ***Array*** in Kotlin? Which one is better in which conditions?

Comment: Those are two different data structures, (nearly?) each programming language has implementation of set and array. Shortly Set-s does not allow duplicates, Array - well it does allow.

Comment: @marcinj thanks, but I expect a more precise answer, like what properties they have, when they are useful etc

Comment: Set and Array are basic data structures common across many (if not all) languages. You should have no issue finding resources online regarding that topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: an Array is an indexed data structure holding a fixed number of items; a Set is an unordered data structure holding items with no duplicates.  Both are typed.

Long answer:

In basic terms, an array in Kotlin is like most other languages: a data structure holding values of the same type.  Arrays have a fixed length, are ordered, and accessed randomly by index (starting from 0).

An Array maps directly to a Java array.  This is the only data structure that the JVM provides, other than Object.  (In fact, array types are treated as special subtypes of Object.)  These are typed: you can have an array of a primitive type (e.g. an array of ints), or of a reference type (e.g. an array of Numbers).  The type is available at run-time, and enforced.  Arrays are treated as being covariant (which can cause run-time errors).

In Kotlin/JVM, `Array` inherits almost all those features (except for covariance).  It's used only for arrays of reference types; Kotlin provides separate classes for arrays of primitives (`IntArray` &c).

And in basic terms, a `Set` is like several other languages: an unordered data structure holding items of the same type, none of which are equal.

`Set` is an interface that's part of the Java Collections framework (which also includes `Collection`, `List`, and `Map`).  A `Set` value can point to any object implementing that interface.  It's generic, with a single type parameter specifying what values can be stored in the set; this happens at compile time (only).

In Kotlin, `Set` is covariant, and read-only; there's a `MutableSet` subinterface which adds mutator methods.  `MutableSet`s are variable-size, and grow and shrink as needed.

There are many different implementations of the `Set` (and `MutableSet`) interface, with different performance characteristics: insertion, removal, and testing for presernce may be O(1) or O(n) or something in-between, and the memory usage and concurrency differ too.

`Set`s can be iterated, but the order is not specified in general.  (Some implementations may make guarantees about whether the order is consistent, and if so, whether/how it relates to the values and/or how they were added.)

So, which should you use?  If you need to prevent duplicates, then a `Set` is the obvious choice.  Whereas if you need the values to be ordered, then an `Array` would be more suitable -- though because it's not part of the Collections framework, it doesn't always play well with other collection types.  (Kotlin provides many extension methods to try to smooth over the gap, but there are still many corner cases.)  So in general, it's usually better to use a `List` instead: that gives you finer control over mutability, avoids some awkward situations (especially regarding type parameters), doesn't fix the length, gives you many more extension methods, and is one character shorter!

Answer (score 0):

Set does not allow duplicate elements where arrays allows.It depends on the requirements. 
If the requirement is to have only unique values then Set is your best bet as any implementation of Set maintains unique values only.